# On Receive SMS BroadCast Receiver works only on android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager

This is my Java class for SMS Receive. It works perfectly on Android 2.3.3 Emulator when it received SMS, It toasts the sms message Receivers number and then the message content.

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    public static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null){
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++){
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }
                for (SmsMessage message : messages){

                    String strMessageFrom = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String strMessageBody = message.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message received from:" +strMessageFrom, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message content" +strMessageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxx" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But When I run this code on android 4.0 Emulator, android 5.1.1 and My real Android 5.0.2 device it does not work like in the Android 2.3.3 Emulator( the do not toast a message on receiving sms.)

Any Idea?